# Wordpress URL Problems and Layout

Tags: custom-post-types, genesis-theme-framework

Why is that the layout of 2 homepage is different.

When i put `http://localhost/mysite/home/`

the layout looks ok and the blog list is there.. there's no problem here.. 
but when i click home it automatically goes to this url ...

`http://localhost/mysite/`
and the blog post listing is gone ...

I created a page called 'Home' and it's using a custom template... and its set as the 'Front Page' located in SETTINGS >> READING

here's the code for my custom template ...

```
<?php /*
Template Name: List BLog
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
  <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
  <div id="content" class="hfeed">
    <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
    <?php query_posts( $args );  ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></h2>
      <div class="postmetadata"> Posted in:
        <?php the_category(', ') ?>
        |
        <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- end #content -->
  <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>
</div>
<!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm not sure what's happening. Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you set as the "Front Page" in `Settings -> Reading` is going to show up here-- `http://localhost/mysite/`-- no matter what its address might otherwise be. I can't tell if you want that address or this one, though: `http://localhost/mysite/home/`

I can tell that the template is broken. The `$args` variable here:

```
query_posts( $args );
```

... isn't set and so that query returns nothing, hence "the blog post listing is gone".

There are a number of genesis functions in there. I am not sure what they do but perhaps that is why the template work here-- `http://localhost/mysite/home/`-- but not here-- `http://localhost/mysite/`... _if I am reading you right.

You should be aware that using `query_posts` inside a template like that is very bad form. It causes a second set of queries to the database making it very inefficient. [There is a note in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> It should be noted that using this to replace the main query on a page
>   can increase page loading times, in worst case scenarios more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more. While easy to use, the
>   function is also prone to confusion and problems later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.

Again, I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish but I think that [you should be using either `home.php` or `front-page.php` for this purpose](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) instead of creating a page and setting that to the "Front Page" as you have. What you've done would be a good approach if you want a mostly static front page that still have editable content. To display a blog list, it is a bit inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks i'm still learning PHP stuff..  so what i did now is I deleted the custom page template. Set the `Front page displays` to `Your latest posts` .... and my home.php is the same as the code above.. only w/o the `query_posts( $args );` and featured image stuff..   I got my blog list showing now! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To set a custom template for front page it's better use another template which is called `front-page.php`and if you look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), it's also the first file WP is looking for when loading front page.

So copy/paste your code into another file you call `front-page.php`and see if it's working. If not there probably an error in your installation settings.